Flutter Error org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
I'm building an App in Flutter, and IDE is Android Studio, when I add cached_network_image or shared_preferences in dependencies: Pub get > Process finished with exit code 0, but when I build my project to run it ends up in error:
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N950F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: file:///C:/Users/DELL/StudioProjects/flutter_app_test/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flutter_app_test/MainActivity.kt:3:8 Unresolved reference: io
e: file:///C:/Users/DELL/StudioProjects/flutter_app_test/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flutter_app_test/MainActivity.kt:5:21 Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Even, I tried to install Flutter on new computer and created new project and with these dependencies gives me same error. I've Googled about this issue but couldn't find any solution to this.

I have solved this problem by downgrading Flutter and Android Studio. I don't know the exact issue but downgrading helped.
